# How to get the Result from previous activity?

Tags: workflow, .net-4.5, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am new to WF 4.5.

The "GenerateResult" activity will generate a string in the Result property.

I want to assign the Result to the varExternal in the following Assign activity.

How to?

[image]

The GeneratedResult activity is defined as below.

```
public sealed class GenerateResult<TResult> : NativeActivity<TResult>
{
    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        this.Result.Set(context, "Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like you'd do it when programming.  You have to hold the result within a variable, then reference that variable elsewhere.

I'm assuming you want to use the result in the WriteLine activity, so you would create a variable within the workflow (look at the bottom of the designer), bind it to the Result property of your GenerateResult activity (it's in the Property grid, so right-click and hit Properties).  Then you can reference that variable in the WriteLine activity.

Comment: Thanks. But what's blocking me is *how to bind the variable to the Result property of the GeneratedResult activity*. I looked at the Property grid of the variable. There're options to set the Scope, Default, Modifier, etc. But no hint to do the binding.

Comment: I found the answer here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/05/25/passing-values-between-workflow-activities.aspx

Comment: @smwikipedia: That's odd, because that's exactly what I said, except that NativeActivity<T> has a Result property which holds the result of the activity.  But you still bind it (via the property grid, "MyOutArg" in the example from the link) to a variable defined on the workflow ("MyVariable" in the example from the link).